# What are submodifiers?

Tags: adverbs, terminology

I wrote a sentence, and my teacher said something was wrong:

> Such an unfortunate man could **surprisingly** live to 73 years old 400 years ago.

She said that "surprisingly" was a submodifier, which couldn't be used to modify a verb but an adjective. I don't understand the reason behind. Is there any way to determine whether an adverb can describe a verb / an adjective / both?

Comment: Didn't she say you need to place a verb "be" after "to"?

Comment: @Rathony No, she didn't. Could "live to be" be replaced by "live until"? Thanks!

Comment: Well, ask her again. She will think about it and let you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

She's wrong. You can use it both ways:

"The train, surprisingly, ran late" => The train is normally on time, and it was surprising that it was late. 'Surprisingly' affects the verb phrase 'ran late'

"The train ran surprisingly late" => You might have expected a train to run late, but it was surprising how late it was. 'Surprisingly' is only modifying the adverb 'late'.

Comment: Thank you! May I ask the terminology used to describe "surprisingly" for each of the above examples? They are both adverbs, right? What is a submodifier?

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer does a good job explaining the difference in meaning with the placement of an adverb being different but it doesn't answer your question "What are submodifiers?"

"Submodifier" is short for **subordinate modifier**. It comes from the fact that submodifiers are used to modify other modifiers. A submodifier is an adverb that is placed before another modifier (an adjective or an adverb) and modifies that modifier. For example, in

> You are very good at running quickly.

*Very* is a submodifier in this sentence, while the other adverb "quickly" isn't.